# Working of rand() and mt_rand() functions in php

Tags: php, algorithm, random, frequency

The random number generation functions work based on the **pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) algorithm**. And according to this algorithm each value in the set from random number is to be chosen will have **equal frequency** in the output.

I would like to know why the same doesn't stand true when tested for **small counts**. Say I run a loop to print rand(1,2) ten times, I find an unequal frequency of occurrence for 1 and 2.

Does the point of **equal frequency stand only when tested over a very large count value**?

Comment: Try flipping a coin and counting heads and tails. Each flip is a unique event, not influenced by prior events.

Comment: That, I do understand, but the PRNG algorithm does state about the equal frequency. Why doesn't that stand true for a small scale test?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you will find that what they say is that each number has equal *probability,* not equal *frequency.*  This is, in other words, an "un-weighted probability distribution."

Consider "ten coin-flips."  If the first five flips were Heads, then the remaining five would have to be Tails.  (And the PRNG would have to somehow know that you intended to flip "ten" times.)  This outcome would no longer be random at all, but pre-ordained.

As every gambler knows, the fact that a fair dice has 1/6 probability of landing sixes-up (or any-other number up ...) does not dictate what face *will* come up.